# What is brackets (The code editor) built on top of?

Tags: web-application, brackets

So, I know that Brackets is based off of a web browser, but is Brackets built in electron.js or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets is [based](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Hack-on-Brackets#how-brackets-is-organized) on the Chromium Embedded Framework:

> Brackets is primarily built in HTML/JS/CSS, but it currently runs as a desktop app inside a thin native app shell called brackets-shell, based on CEF, that lets it access local files.